# Unable to print the background image which is in div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, devexpress

```
function PrintSVG() {

    var container = $('#MainDesignerPanelContainer');
    var width = parseFloat(svg.getAttribute("width"));
    var height = parseFloat(svg.getAttribute("height"));
    var printWindow = window.open('', 'MainDesignerPanelContainer',
            'width=' + width + ',height=' + height);
    printWindow.document.write($(container).html());
    $(printWindow.document).find('#panningDiv').remove();

    printWindow.document.close();
    printWindow.print();
    printWindow.close();
};
```

I cannot print the background image only it is printing the SVG Elements.
Can you please tell me what is the mistake i am doing here

Comment: Well i guess the thing you can do is set the background image on the page itself with `z-index:-1;`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a browser setting wether to print background images or not, nothing you can do about in Javascript.

Comment: Hi,
i changed the Setting to Print background images.. its still not working

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
function PrintSVG() {
  var container = $('#MainDesignerPanelContainer');
  var html = container.html();  // <------------cache the html 
  var width = parseFloat(svg.getAttribute("width"));
  var height = parseFloat(svg.getAttribute("height"));
  var printWindow = window.open('', 'MainDesignerPanelContainer',
    'width=' + width + ',height=' + height);
  var imgSrc = container.css('background-image'); // <----get the imgSrc
  html.append($('<img>', {
    src: imgSrc,
    style: "position:absolute; z-index:-1;"
  })); // Add it to the existing html

  printWindow.document.write(html); // <------write the html

  $(printWindow.document).find('#panningDiv').remove();

  printWindow.document.close();
  printWindow.print();
  printWindow.close();
};
```

Comment: Image Changes Dynamically.. For each user they have different background Image

Comment: `container.css('background-image');` is what it gets. specific to each user.